# Network issues with Jio sim on Sim slot 1 and Airtel on Sim slot 2

Tags: connection-issues

I have Jio sim on Sim slot 1 and Airtel on Sim slot 2.Both the slots are 4G enabled and have VolLte. Whenever I turn on Airtel data , Jio goes out of coverage and unavailable. What would be the problem ? Is it a network issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply compatibility issues.

A quick Google search shows that AirTel use FDD-LTE as their standard, while Jio use TD-LTE.

Due to current technology restrictions, TD-LTE can't stay on when FDD-LTE cellular data connection is established. So it's absolutely normal that your Jio card runs out of service when you turn on mobile data for AirTel.